# Enabling / disabling captions in jwplayer with javascript?

Tags: javascript, plugins, jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer nad all works fine. 
I'm trying to add an external link that would call some javascript to enable / disable the captions.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Thanks !

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't... yet
http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/ticket/1122